# Is there a way to convert a series of images in a folder to a PDF from the command line on Win10?

Tags: pdf

I want to convert the images(jpg) in the **destination folder** to a pdf file from the command line silence, without GUI.

I tried many pdf command line programs like imageMagick, pdftk, img2pdf, jpg2pdf, verypdf

Some of them can't convert the input folder, just only the image files, not even just like `C:\*.png C:\1.pdf`

and some of them can't keep the **Portrait** of the image in the output pdf.

I just want the command line like this:
`xpdf.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1 -o C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.pdf`

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for off-site resources are specifically off-topic here. See the [help/on-topic]

Comment: So you want all images in the source folder to be in one pdf? Or do you want to have every single image in a single pdf?

Comment: All images in a pdf file

Answer (score 0):

I support SumatraPDF, where, one of its lesser known features was, from GUI convert a Comic Book into a simple PDF without much additional overheads. Thus would need a version prior to 3.5 and I would suggest 3.1.2 was most stable.

SumatraPDF (Limited free for commercial use license) is based on MuPDF and that itself has a free for private use licensed approach.

Hence the following suggestion is not free for commercial users.

The command line tool is MuTool (an .exe for windows) which has a convert command which will thus do the same i.e. convert a zip folder of images into a PDF.

So to convert 3 copies of a PNG into PDF pages, the process is along these lines

```
tar -a -cf folder.zip folder\*.png
mutool convert -o folder.pdf folder.zip
```

[image]

There will be a noticeable difference in the resulting file size, since SumatraPDF will produce a file 2,348 bytes by using compression, but mutool will convert as uncompressed bitmaps so generate 8,305 bytes for the same 3 small images.

To generate a compressed file of 2,269 bytes (smaller than SumatraPDF) you will need to add the
`-O compress` option

It should be possible to de duplicate those images to make the file even smaller, however I could not get that functionality to work, for these 3 objects.